# Awk fixed width columns and left leaning columns

Tags: awk

I have a file named file1 consisting of 4350 lines and 12 columns, as shown below.

```
ATOM      1  CE1 LIG H   1      75.206  62.966  59.151  0.00  0.00      HAB1  
ATOM      2  NE2 LIG H   1      74.984  62.236  58.086  0.00  0.00      HAB1  
ATOM      3  CD2 LIG H   1      74.926  63.041  57.027  0.00  0.00      HAB1  
.
.
.
ATOM   4348  ZN  ZN2 H   1       1.886  22.818  51.215  0.00  0.00      HAC1  
ATOM   4349  ZN  ZN2 H   1      62.517  30.663   5.219  0.00  0.00      HAC1  
ATOM   4350  ZN  ZN2 H   1      59.442  35.851   2.791  0.00  0.00      HAC1
```

I am using `awk -v d="74.106" '{$7=sprintf("%0.3f", $7+d)} 1' file1 > file2`  to add a value d to the 7th column of file1. After this, my file2 does not retain the correct formatting. A section of file2 is shown below.

```
ATOM 1 CE1 LIG H 1 149.312 62.966 59.151 0.00 0.00 HAB1
ATOM 2 NE2 LIG H 1 149.090 62.236 58.086 0.00 0.00 HAB1
ATOM 3 CD2 LIG H 1 149.032 63.041 57.027 0.00 0.00 HAB1
.
.
.
ATOM 4348 ZN ZN2 H 1 75.992 22.818 51.215 0.00 0.00 HAC1
ATOM 4349 ZN ZN2 H 1 136.623 30.663 5.219 0.00 0.00 HAC1
ATOM 4350 ZN ZN2 H 1 133.548 35.851 2.791 0.00 0.00 HAC1
```

I need my file2 to keep the same formatting as my file1, where only columns 2, 8, and 9 are left leaning.
I have tried to use `awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="7 6 4 4 4 5 8 8 8 6 6 10" '{print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 $10 $11 $12}'` to specify the maximum width for each of the 12th columns. This line does not change my file2. Moreover, I cannot find a way to make columns 2, 8, and 9 left leaning as in file1.
How can I achieve these two things?

I appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Read about [Fixed Width Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html)

Answer (score 3):

Well, with the default `FS`, `awk` strips the duplicate spaces when you modify a field.

What you need to do first is to understand your **ATOM** record format:

| COLUMNS | DATA TYPE | CONTENTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - 6 | Record name | "`ATOM` " |
| 7 - 11 | Integer | Atom serial number. |
| 13 - 16 | Atom | Atom name. |
| 17 | Character | Alternate location indicator. |
| 18 - 20 | Residue name | Residue name. |
| 22 | Character | Chain identifier. |
| 23 - 26 | Integer | Residue sequence number. |
| 27 | AChar | Code for insertion of residues. |
| 31 - 38 | Real(8.3) | Orthogonal coordinates for X in Angstroms. |
| 39 - 46 | Real(8.3) | Orthogonal coordinates for Y in Angstroms. |
| 47 - 54 | Real(8.3) | Orthogonal coordinates for Z in Angstroms. |
| 55 - 60 | Real(6.2) | Occupancy. |
| 61 - 66 | Real(6.2) | Temperature factor (Default = 0.0). |
| 73 - 76 | LString(4) | Segment identifier, left-justified. |
| 77 - 78 | LString(2) | Element symbol, right-justified. |
| 79 - 80 | LString(2) | Charge on the atom. |

Then you can use `substr` for generating a modified record:

```bash
awk -v d="74.106" '
    /^ATOM  / {
        xCoord = sprintf( "%8.3f", substr($0,31,8) + d )
        $0 = substr($0,1,30) xCoord substr($0,39)
    }
    1
' file.pdb
```

```
ATOM      1  CE1 LIG H   1     149.312  62.966  59.151  0.00  0.00      HAB1  
ATOM      2  NE2 LIG H   1     149.090  62.236  58.086  0.00  0.00      HAB1  
ATOM      3  CD2 LIG H   1     149.032  63.041  57.027  0.00  0.00      HAB1  
.
.
.
ATOM   4348  ZN  ZN2 H   1      75.992  22.818  51.215  0.00  0.00      HAC1  
ATOM   4349  ZN  ZN2 H   1     136.623  30.663   5.219  0.00  0.00      HAC1  
ATOM   4350  ZN  ZN2 H   1     133.548  35.851   2.791  0.00  0.00      HAC1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -v d=74.106 '/ATOM/{sub($7,sprintf("%0.3f", $7+d))}1' input_file
ATOM      1  CE1 LIG H   1      149.312  62.966  59.151  0.00  0.00      HAB1  
ATOM      2  NE2 LIG H   1      149.090  62.236  58.086  0.00  0.00      HAB1  
ATOM      3  CD2 LIG H   1      149.032  63.041  57.027  0.00  0.00      HAB1  
.
.
.
ATOM   4348  ZN  ZN2 H   1       75.992  22.818  51.215  0.00  0.00      HAC1  
ATOM   4349  ZN  ZN2 H   1      136.623  30.663   5.219  0.00  0.00      HAC1  
ATOM   4350  ZN  ZN2 H   1      133.548  35.851   2.791  0.00  0.00      HAC1
```

Comment: [Law of the Instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)